# How to Display A Group of Dynamically Generated Buttons Vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm making a jQuery slideshow using the jQuery cycle plugin.

Part of the code generates a few `<input type="button">` elements with a `value` from `1` to `i` (where `i` equals the total number of slides)

I'm trying to style these buttons so that they appear on top of the image in the slideshow.
I have that part ok. However they line up horizontally across the image and I'd like to display them vertically on top of the image.

How do I go about doing this?

This is currently what my CSS looks like:

```
input[type=button] {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 750px;
    z-index: 1000;

}
```

Comment: Remove . after and  before in you css

Comment: add display:block to your css, as per my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this**

```css
input[type=button] {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 750px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**into this**

```css
input[type=button] {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 750px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Not used to `float: center` this is `wrong property`

used to only `float: left` and `float: right;`

More about **[Float](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)**

Comment: So aside from the float. How to I make the buttons lineup vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Give to the parent text-align: center

Comment: I give you two example first is this http://tinkerbin.com/Rpgu6FRf and second is this http://tinkerbin.com/L8GuxtzR

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect by adding `display:block` to your inputs.. http://jsfiddle.net/NqN5y/6/

```
input[type=button] {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;    
    left: 350px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display:block;
}
```

another easy solution is to contain the buttons in a div. Set a fixed width for the div and bingo.

http://jsfiddle.net/NqN5y/1/

```
<div id="buttons">
<input type="button" value="1"/>
<input type="button" value="2"/>
<input type="button" value="3"/>
<input type="button" value="4"/>
</div>
```

```css
input[type=button] {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 350px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#buttons{width:50px;}
```

You can then move your position styles to the container div.. http://jsfiddle.net/NqN5y/5/

```css
input[type=button] {
    padding:10px;
}

#buttons{width:50px;background-color:#afa;
    position: relative;
    left: 350px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```